# Dependent picklists in components conflicting with each other

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dependent-picklist

Imagine an object called Location that has a Country, State, and City dependent picklists. You select a Country then the States are populated, you select a state then the Cities are populated. Now imagine you have two components, the first component is called SourceLocation and the second component is called DestinationLocation. Both components are included in a VF page called MyLocations, the component controllers have their respective variable Location sourceLocation and variable Location destinationLocation that are rendered and referenced in each component.

The issue I am facing is it appears the mechanism Salesforce uses to make dependent picklists work conflicts with itself if there are two sets of picklists from two separate object instances on the same VF page. When I try to use the picklists the SourceLocation it messes up the picklists on the other component. However, If I only include one component on the VF page it all works perfectly. Is there a way to scope the components so that the included javascript Salesforce uses to make them work doesn't collide with itself?

Comment: While your description is quite detailed, including your code may help.